# Extract name from name card details

Tags: java, regex

Can anyone tell me how to extract the name from the below detail?

```
Singapore Polytechnic 

Daniel Rossey
Manager

66556652
test@gmail.com
```

I just want to match only name "Daniel Rossey" and my current expression below does not work

```
^[A-z][A-z|\.|\s]+$
```

It will match "Manager" and "Singapore Polytechnic" too.

Please do not suggest me a regular expression like this one below:

```
\n[A-Z][A-Za-z ]+
```

This is because this expression extract "Daniel Rossey" just because it appears on the 3rd line, this cannot work for me as the name will not always belong in the 3rd line for my case.

**I want to form a regex that:**

- Match names that have 2 up to 4 words
- Exclude words "Polytechnic" or "University"

How do I do that?

Comment: This isn't a regex problem, it's a text parsing problem.  If each chunk in your input file has the above format, then you need to extract the third line and store it.  Trying to cook up a complex regex to span multiple lines of input is not the way to go here, IMHO.

Comment: why not make that thing like this: Company: Singapore Polytechnic Name: Daniel Rossey Role: Manager Phone number: 66556652 email: test@gmail.com and then read that thing and when inputstring.contains("name"), read that full name and store it.

Comment: as Tim said, this isn't a regex problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex for the stated problem:

```
^(?!.*\b(Polytechnic|University)\b) *[A-Za-z][A-Za-z.]*(?: +[A-Za-z.]+){1,3} *$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vH8wQ1/1)

`(?!.*\b(Polytechnic|University)\b)` is negative lookahead to fail the match if these keywords appear anywhere in the input line. Rest is for matching 2-4 words.